# mongodb is not running on my Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, installation

I'm trying to follow a MongoDB example for learning matters.
The instructions say that after starting MongoDB I will have a mongodb terminal so I can create a database and make it the active one.

The problem is that I start mongodb but I don't have the application terminal, it runs but at the end I have the ubuntu's terminal.

I followed this https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/ to install Mongo:

pip install pymongo

wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-5.0.asc | sudo apt-key add -

echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/5.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-5.0.list

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org

I also installed COMPASS, this is running correctly
wget https://downloads.mongodb.com/compass/mongodb-compass_1.26.1_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i mongodb-compass_1.26.1_amd64.deb

mongodb-compass

---

I'm starting Mongo

sudo systemctl start mongod  #this do something but takes me back to the terminal prompt.

mongosh  #is launching this "MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017"

---

Definitely I'm doing something wrong but I cannot identify it.
Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: could you provide log of 
journalctl -f -u mongod.service

Comment: Hint: You are currently not seeing messages from other users and the system.
      Users in groups 'adm', 'systemd-journal' can see all messages.
      Pass -q to turn off this notice.
-- Logs begin at Fri 2021-09-10 19:51:47 CDT. --

Comment: Does the mongod log show anything useful?